# JavadocでXML内の */ を記述する方法

Tags: java

以下のようなJavadocコメントを残したいと考えています。

```
XMLでは以下のように設定してください。
<hoge path="/**/*.html" />
```

しかし、以下のように書くと、アスタリスクースラッシュ（*/）があるせいでうまくいきませんでした。

```
/**
 * XMLでは以下のように設定してください。
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * <xml>
 *    <hoge path="/**/*.html" />
 * </xml>
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

<pre>や{@code}を使わずに、一つ一つエスケープしていくというのは１つの手かとは思いますが、実際に残したいコメントはXML部分が非常に長いため、XML部分は必要以上にエスケープしたくありません。

{@literal *}としてみたり、スラッシュを&#47;でエスケープする方法も試しましたが、<pre>（または{@code}？）を使っているせいか、うまくいきませんでした。

なにか妙案あれば、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: `*` と `/` の間に zero width space(U+200B)を入れるとか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。zero width spaceを使うことでエラーは解消し、見た目上も問題なくなりました。ただ、コピペには向かないので、payanekoさんにご指摘いただいたとおり、コピペをするなら別リンクを参照するように誘導するコメントを残すようにしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

妙案ではありませんが 運用例として回答します。

私は本家スタックオーバーフローの[類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/631817)に対する回答のように、愚直にコメントの一括置換で対応しています。
その上でjavadocから生成したヘルプページへとコメント内で誘導します。
(ヘルプページはCIツールや夜間バッチなどで定期的に更新します)

多少不便かもしれませんが、ルール化しておけば他の開発者もそれに従ってAPIリファレンスが充実してくるので、運用で困ったことはありません。

```
/**
 * Returns true if the specified string contains "*/".
 *  ↓ "/" を "&#47;" に一括置換
 * Returns true if the specified string contains "*&#47;".
 * @see <a href="http://社内Webサーバ/doxygen/hoge/fuga.html">xmlサンプルをコピペしたい場合はこちら</a>
 */
public boolean containsSpecialSequence(String str)
```

※社内ではjava以外の言語を使っているので雰囲気でとらえてください。`@see`の構文が間違っていたらすみません。